# DetailView with Python

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, django-views

i am new to django/python...i am trying to develop an educational site with django. i have a query in listview and detailview. How can i set the path in the url for detailedview when i dnt have any primary key to grab the path..[ the post/questions of which i need the detailview are posted by students themselves like that similar to quora].

`urlpatterns = [
path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='blog-home'),
path('post/<int:pk>', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
path('about/', views.about, name='blog-about'),`

what should i place in place of int:pk as i dnt have any primary key

Thanks in advance

Comment: You do, for sure, need a primary key - and that's regardless of whether you are connecting to this database with Django. It's just poor database design to not have a key column. So, add one and then you'll also solve your issue of how to structure the URLs for the questions.

Comment: How about i grab the path by the whole question itself? if it is possible how to do that?